# Tor everything. VPN -> Tpr

Tags: vpn, tunnel

so just a quick question. How can I send all my traffic through Tor?
I'm on a work computer with an IT department monitoring all our traffic.
Not that I do anything not permitted on the computers but I'd like to send all traffic through Tor.
It's a Windows 7 pc (sadly) and I don't have admin rights.
I'm able to set up a pptp tunnel though but I don't know how to configure the pptp server to redirect all traffic through Tor. The pptp server is an Ubuntu 14.04 server.

I know pptp isn't the safest thing out there but I don't have access to openvpn or anything like that.
If you have other suggestions then don't hesitate to post them.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest way is to buy a safeplug box. https://pogoplug.com/safeplug
The box acts as a proxy for your computer to talk to Tor. What you need to do is to configure your computer to re-direct all connections to Safeplug.
P/s: Safeplug uses Privoxy as and proxy to talk to Tor. So if you are capable of configure Privoxy within your PC to talk to Tor, then you could save amount of money on buying the box.